# В чем проблема с кодировкой title?

Tags: html, mysql, кодировка

На двух страницах начало html одинаковое:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Но Title на одной выводится нормально, русскими буквами, а на другой (где title берется частично из mysql c кодировкой utf8_general_ci) кракозябрами.
Как исправить?

P.S.
Заработало само после рандомных действий

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте изменить кодировку самого файла. Элементарно в notepade++ перекодируйте в переоброзовать utf8(без BOM)

Comment: Уже стоит такая в n++.

Comment: @Kir тогда попробуйте написать русские символы сами (а не из базы). Если выводиться нормально то нужно перед тем как выводить кадировку строки определять

Comment: В тайтле есть русские символы не из базы, сейчас попробую просто текст оставить

Comment: Не помогло, все равно кракозябры

Comment: После подключения к БД выставите кодировку, например:
 $conn->set_charset("utf8");

Comment: @Nilsan есть еще варианты исправления? пользуюcm safemysql и не знаю, как поменять кодировку

Comment: Хотя в другом хроме буквы нормально показывает

Comment: @Kir - а в safemysql стоит кодировка? И не совсем понятно "в другом хроме", другая версия или на другом устройстве?

Comment: @Nilsan тут бд ни причем. Когда статичный текст вручную пишешь все равно кодировка нарушается. Тут что-то с файлом

Comment: @Nilsan в ungoogled chrome нормально показывалось. Решение оказалось в kint, как я понял. Убрал и заработало.

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
```

попробуйте вставить такое вместо старого тега мета. Это тег мета по стандартом html4